# Make components display with if in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two type of elements which I get from WordPress theme panel to show things but I want their column shows only if they have variable.

These are my codes which I need to be add `if` tags before those:

For text:

```
<?php $sample_text_field = get_option('RobertNicjoo_sample_aonename'); echo $sample_text_field; ?>
```

For Image:

```
<?php $sample_image_upload = get_option('RobertNicjoo_sample_aone'); echo '<img src="'.$sample_image_upload.'" alt="agent" />'; ?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you give more info about your issue. It's not entirely clear what you need and where you need it.

Comment: I want to say if for example `RobertNicjoo_sample_aone` got variable show if not nothing. like `<?php if (.......); { ?>` `<?php } ?>` but i dont know how to make that for this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
<?php $sample_text_field = get_option('RobertNicjoo_sample_aonename');
(isset($sample_text_field) && $sample_text_field != '') ? echo $sample_text_field : '';?>
```

Or

```
<?php $sample_text_field = get_option('RobertNicjoo_sample_aonename');
    if(isset($sample_text_field) && $sample_text_field != ''){
        echo $sample_text_field;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this :

```
<?php 
    $sample_text_field = get_option('RobertNicjoo_sample_aonename');
    $sample_text_field_flag = ! empty($sample_text_field) ? true : false;

    if($sample_text_field_flag){
        echo $sample_text_field;    
    }
?>
```

You can do same for Image code also.

Let me know If you have any doubt.